# Proving equality of determinants of sums of matrices

Tags: matrices, determinant

I'm trying to prove that when X is an arbitrary matrix and Y is an invertible matrix of the same dimensions,

${det(X - aI) = det(YXY^{-1} - aI)}$

implies,

${det(X) = det(YXY^{-1})}$

How do I go about proving this claim? I tried to expand the matrices component-wise but I got nowhere and I'm stuck.

Comment: In general, if $A,B$ are square matrices, then $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$.  Are you able to appeal to this theorem?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question: do you want to *deduce* the second equality from the first one? And in the first one, is $a$ a fixed number or a polynomial indeterminate (if so, just evaluate at $a=0$). And how did you get the first one (which is generally *deduced* from the *more elementary* second one, applied to $X'=X-aI$)?

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes I'm trying to deduce the 2nd equality from the 1st one and I hope to eventually prove the 1st equality using the result. Maybe, there's an easier approach to proving it? Also, a is a real scalar and aI is just the identity matrix multiplied by a real number and the first equality relates to the characteristic equation of eigenvalues.

Comment: The easiest approach is to prove first the second equality (using Brian Moehring's hint), and then replace X by X-aI in this second equality to deduce the first one.